# Options for Linux NAS Software

Tags: dual-boot, nas

I am looking for some NAS Linux software. After research all I have found are OSs such as FreeNAS and FreeBSD. But my server is already running Linux Mate and has lots of config which is required as it is hosting multiple websites. So I was wondering if there are any alternatives which are plain software which will run on my existing Linux install which are not an OS. Or, would I be better off just dual booting with one of the mentioned OSs?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're after.  I mean, if you have a computer that is hosting multiple web sites, once you dual boot and are in the other OS, these web sites are inaccessible...  If your computer has a set of drives and you just want to be able to use it on a network, what is wrong with just [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html.en)?  If you want Dropbox-like syncing, you can consider [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/).

Comment: @Ray Sorry I wasn't clear in my question. As I discovered yesterday after setting up a Samba share, the SMB protocol is too insecure to allow external connections, so I was looking for software which is essentially samba which would allow external connections. So i'm really looking for NAS software, I will have a look into OwnCloud now :)

Comment: I have my own answer, but SMBv3 with an appropriate `iptables` rule set should limit your attack scope.

Comment: @LucaPassariello I can't say I know much about SMB's security, but a cursory search came up with postings like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/657942/encrypting-smb-traffic-with-samba).  There seems to be encryption; so I'm curious what worries you about SMB.  OwnCloud can use https.  But, as user38537 says, you can set up a firewall for either OwnCloud and SMB.  Either way, it sounds like dual booting is not the right way to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Install the web and other services to your installation on your own (e.g. Nextcloud, Owncloud, mail server, Web server, Samba, etc.)
2. Use pre-configured scripts e.g. Yunohost in order to automate the installation of other services.

The point No. 1 requires a deeper knowledge of each service, how to install and configure. Option No.2 includes pre-configured install and configuration scripts via web interface.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the services you want to be made available. If you only have *nix clients, you can mount the share via SSHFS. Mountain Duck for Windows and Mac can mount SSHFS paths. On Windows, it assigns the share a drive letter. WinSCP for Windows can also use SSH to get files, but that's similar to an FTP server GUI interface.

A Samba share isn't that hard to set up either. That can have windows and *nix clients.